# Linq and Entity Framework cannot be translated

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

To be specific, I have an entity in cosmo declared as a dbset:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to search by a specific tag, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'u => u.Tags' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The implementation to get this error is:

```
var users = await _context.Users
                          .SelectMany(u => u.Tags)
                          .Where(p => p == tag)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Some idea?

Please note that load all data in memory by `users.ToListAsync` first is not an option.

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` statement that EF generated for your `User` class. We need to see how it mapped `List<String> Tags` to RDMBS tables...

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, its likely that the server doesn't support storing lists. You'll probably need to create a separate table to store the strings and create a foreign key constraint between that table and `Users`.

Comment: there is no migration. Its just a collection in cosmodb.  Just a context like this        


 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .ToContainer("Users") 
                .HasPartitionKey(e => e.Id);


By the way, all data is stored ok

Comment: @ChacaLitos _"By the way, all data is stored ok"_ - famous last words...

Comment: BTW,, your Linq query won't return any `User` objects - it will simply return the `String` values in `Tags` that match the `tag` query parameter argument, which is a low-utility query: `.SelectMany(u => u.Tags)` yields `IQueryable<String>` - not `IQueryable<User>`.

Comment: @Dai , indeed... but trying to get user cannot translate a contains

Comment: Did you try `var users = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Tags.Any(t => t == tag)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: yes, same result .......   System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 't => t == __tag_0' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 lambdaExpression)

Comment: you should try .Where(p => p.property == tag.property)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Finally i separated in a  different collection. So, i can query bu user and tag one by one

Comment: The answer you provided is unclear. To help others, include more detail in what you did and how it solved the issue you had. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).